# didReceiveMemoryWarning from UITableView with Images created with url data followed by app termination due to memory pressure

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, memory, uiimageview

I am setting up a UITableview, and on the side of each cell is an image that is 80x80. The TableView works perfectly when the number of cells is less than 8, but any more than this and sometimes the scroll performance can have a minor delay. With a lot more cells (around 50), the scroll performance is fine as long as you dont make a big swipe down quickly. Also, when there are a lot of cells, if you stay on this view for too long and scroll up and down, the app will receive a memory warning, and then will eventually crash. Any tips for helping to save memory? Some of these images are pretty large (5000 x 1000), or how to clear some memory when didReceiveMemoryWarning is called? I'm using ARC if that is relevant. Here is the code I use to set up the cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ArticleCell"];

if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"ArticleCell"];
}
cell.titleLabel.text = nil;
cell.imageRight.image = nil;

Article *article = [self.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.titleLabel setText:article.title];

if(!article.pictureData){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:article.image]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            article.pictureData = data;
            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            CGSize imgSize = CGSizeMake(80, 80);
            img = [img resizeImage:img newSize:imgSize];
            [cell.imageRight setImage:img];
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];
        });
    });
} else
[cell.imageRight setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:article.pictureData]];
return cell;
}
```

The point is though that this tableView is loading all of the cells perfectly, and it can make it all the way through even 50+ rows. I just need to clear some memory, I'm just unsure how.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:article.image]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //enter code here
         });
     });
   }

Call this section of code in CustomTableViewCell class.

Comment: how can i call that code in the CustomTableViewCell class when the self.tableview doesn't exist there? I can call the last three lines of that section of code.

Comment: send image url to custom cell class then use same GCD method in custom class to load that image and then do [self.imageright setimage:img].

Comment: Here's what I just tried, which still resulted in memory pressure termination. Within the dispatch_sync code block I put this: article.pictureData = data;
                [cell imageRightWithData:data];
                [self.tableView beginUpdates];
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                [self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: and made a method within the CustomTableView cell like this: -(void)imageRightWithData:(NSData*)data{
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    CGSize imgSize = CGSizeMake(80, 80);
    img = [img resizeImage:img newSize:imgSize];
    [self.imageRight setImage:img];
}

Comment: Move dispatch_sync code block to custom cell class from table method.
and use NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:article.image]]; in that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56319/discussion-between-student-and-rdspinz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cells are set up differently depending on whether the `pictureData` is available:

If `pictureData` is not yet available, it will be downloaded & its *full resolution* data set on the `article` object; afterwards a *smaller thumbnail* image is generated and set on `cell.imageRight`.

However, if the picture has already been downloaded, a *full resolution* image is created from `pictureData` and set on the cell's `imageRight` *without* resizing it first..

```
} else
    [cell.imageRight setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:article.pictureData]];
```

This means that as soon as all pictures have been loaded, each time the tableView dequeues a reusable cell it will also set the *full res image* on `cell.imageRight`. I suppose this explains the memory issues you are encountering.

My advice would be to add a `UIImage *thumbnail` property to the articles object, cache the resized image there after it has been generated from the downloaded data and always use this `-thumbnail` for the cell's `imageRight`. Additionally, this will reduce the nontrivial system load (both on memory & cpu) caused by re-generating and resizing the images every time the tableView updates a cell.

Another thing: there's actually no need to bother the main thread with the image resize operation, I suspect that's where the hitching comes from when scrolling. It should help to leave that on the global queue and `dispatch_async` only the table update to the main queue afterwards.